# VSCode Launch File Debug Configuration for Different Files

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-debugging

I am using VSCode to debug my Python files. I have two scripts, let's say `a.py` and `b.py`. These two files work with differents args. I would like to configure `launch.json` in such a way that, if I run `a.py`, it should input its corresponding args and same for other files. However, there is no if statement in launch file. And if I write two configurations, it just runs them sequentially. What should my `launch.json` look like? Here is my first attempt.

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Python: Current File",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${WorkspaceFolder}/src/data_processing/main.py",
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "env": {
            "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceRoot}"
        },
        "args": [
            "/home/gokberk/Desktop/filtered_data",
            "--gdc",
            "gdc-client",
            "--no-download",
            "--manifest",
            "/home/gokberk/Desktop/filtered_data/gdc_manifest.2021-05-26.txt",
            "--source-slides-folder",
            "/home/gokberk/Desktop/filtered_data"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Python: Current File",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${WorkspaceFolder}/src/training.py",
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "env": {
            "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceRoot}"
        },
        "args": [
            "--input-data-folder",
            "/home/gokberk/Desktop/filtered_data",
            "--alpha",
            "0.2",
            "--beta",
            "0.2",
            "--max-bag-size",
            "50",
            "--underlying-model-type",
            "resnet18",
            "--pretrained",
            "--no-download",
            "--source-slides-folder",
            "/home/gokberk/Desktop/filtered_data"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Comment: Both configurations having same name, probably that might create issue, change name of one of them.  "name": "Python: Current File" => "name": "Python: Current File1"

Answer (score 2):

In VSCode you have to manually choose debug configuration:

[drop down to select configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9lGv.png)

VSCode devs [refused](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/124877) to make this automation.
Instead [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DarrenLevine.auto-debug) for this was made